# Eclipse4.2 WTP Wizard does not generate WSDL file for AXIS2- Tomcat Webservice

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, apache-axis, eclipse-wtp

I've followed the steps in the [tutorial](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BottomUpAxis2WebService/bu_tutorial.html) to create a Webservice.

Everything works fine but there is no WSDL file generated!

I've a dynamic WebProject in which I create the the Webservice.... no errors but no wsdl file generated

I also can't generate the wsdl file afterwards with the axis2 codegen plugin for Eclipse. I keep getting the error `class not found exception`

My axis2 tomcat installation seems to work properly - see my axis2 happiness page below...

I've tried every suggested solution from here in Stack Overflow but without success!

What else can I try to get this working.....

**my config  is:**

Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Juno Release
Build id: 20120614-1722

Fedora 17x64
AXIS2 1.6.2
Tomcat 7

AXIS2 Installation seems to be alight:

```
Axis2 Happiness Page

Examining webapp configuration

Essential Components

Found Apache-Axis (org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet) 
  at /home/pk/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/MyWebService/WEB-INF/lib/axis2-transport-http-1.6.2.jar
Found Jakarta-Commons Logging (org.apache.commons.logging.Log) 
  at /home/pk/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/MyWebService/WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
Found Streaming API for XML (javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader) 
  at an unknown location
Found Streaming API for XML implementation (org.codehaus.stax2.XMLStreamWriter2) 
  at /home/pk/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/MyWebService/WEB-INF/lib/wstx-asl-3.2.9.jar
The core axis2 libraries are present.

Note: Even if everything this page probes for is present, there is no guarantee your Axis Service will work, because there are many configuration options that we do not check for. These tests are necessary but not sufficient

Examining Version Service

Found Axis2 default Version service and Axis2 is working properly.
Now you can drop a service archive in axis2/WEB-INF/services. Following output was produced while invoking Axis2 version service

Hi - the Axis2 version is 1.6.2

Examining Application Server

Servlet version 3.0
Platform    Apache Tomcat/7.0.12
Examining System Properties

java.runtime.name   OpenJDK Runtime Environment 
sun.boot.library.path   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.6.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64 
java.vm.version 23.2-b09 
shared.loader    
java.vm.vendor  Oracle Corporation 
java.vendor.url http: //java.oracle.com/ 
path.separator  :  
java.vm.name    OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 
tomcat.util.buf.StringCache.byte.enabled    true 
file.encoding.pkg   sun.io 
user.country    DE 
sun.java.launcher   SUN_STANDARD 
sun.os.patch.level  unknown 
java.vm.specification.name  Java Virtual Machine Specification 
user.dir    /home/pk/Documents 
java.runtime.version    1.7.0_06-icedtea-mockbuild_2012_08_31_14_28-b00 
java.awt.graphicsenv    sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment 
java.endorsed.dirs  /home/pk/Tomcat70/endorsed 
os.arch amd64 
java.io.tmpdir  /tmp 
line.separator    
java.vm.specification.vendor    Oracle Corporation 
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs    org.apache.naming 
os.name Linux 
sun.jnu.encoding    UTF-8 
java.library.path   /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64: /usr/lib64: /lib64: /lib: /usr/lib 
tomcat.util.scan.DefaultJarScanner.jarsToSkip   bootstrap.jar,commons-daemon.jar,tomcat-juli.jar,annotations-api.jar,el-api.jar,jsp-api.jar,servlet-api.jar,catalina.jar,catalina-ant.jar,catalina-ha.jar,catalina-tribes.jar,jasper.jar,jasper-el.jar,ecj-*.jar,tomcat-api.jar,tomcat-util.jar,tomcat-coyote.jar,tomcat-dbcp.jar,tomcat-i18n-en.jar,tomcat-i18n-es.jar,tomcat-i18n-fr.jar,tomcat-i18n-ja.jar,commons-beanutils*.jar,commons-collections*.jar,commons-dbcp*.jar,commons-digester*.jar,commons-fileupload*.jar,commons-logging*.jar,commons-pool*.jar,ant.jar,jmx.jar,jmx-tools.jar,xercesImpl.jar,xmlParserAPIs.jar,xml-apis.jar,dnsns.jar,ldapsec.jar,localedata.jar,sunjce_provider.jar,sunpkcs11.jar,tools.jar,apple_provider.jar,AppleScriptEngine.jar,CoreAudio.jar,dns_sd.jar,j3daudio.jar,j3dcore.jar,j3dutils.jar,jai_core.jar,jai_codec.jar,mlibwrapper_jai.jar,MRJToolkit.jar,vecmath.jar 
java.specification.name Java Platform API Specification 
java.class.version  51.0 
sun.management.compiler HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers 
os.version  3.5.3-1.fc17.x86_64 
user.home   /home/pk 
user.timezone   Europe/Vienna 
catalina.useNaming  true 
java.awt.printerjob sun.print.PSPrinterJob 
java.specification.version  1.7 
file.encoding   UTF-8 
catalina.home   /home/pk/Tomcat70 
user.name   pk 
java.class.path /home/pk/Tomcat70/bin/bootstrap.jar: /home/pk/Tomcat70/bin/tomcat-juli.jar: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.6.x86_64/lib/tools.jar 
java.naming.factory.initial org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory 
package.definition  sun.,java.,org.apache.catalina.,org.apache.coyote.,org.apache.tomcat.,org.apache.jasper. 
java.vm.specification.version   1.7 
sun.arch.data.model 64 
java.home   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.6.x86_64/jre 
sun.java.command    org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start 
java.specification.vendor   Oracle Corporation 
user.language   de 
awt.toolkit sun.awt.X11.XToolkit 
java.vm.info    mixed mode 
java.version    1.7.0_06-icedtea 
java.ext.dirs   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.6.x86_64/jre/lib/ext: /usr/java/packages/lib/ext 
sun.boot.class.path /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.6.x86_64/jre/lib/resources.jar: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.6.x86_64/jre/lib/rt.jar: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.6.x86_64/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.6.x86_64/jre/lib/jsse.jar: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.6.x86_64/jre/lib/jce.jar: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.6.x86_64/jre/lib/charsets.jar: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.6.x86_64/jre/lib/netx.jar: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.6.x86_64/jre/lib/plugin.jar: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.6.x86_64/jre/lib/rhino.jar: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.6.x86_64/jre/lib/jfr.jar: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.6.x86_64/jre/classes 
java.vendor Oracle Corporation 
server.loader    
catalina.base   /home/pk/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0 
file.separator  / 
java.vendor.url.bug http: //bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/ 
common.loader   ${catalina.base}/lib,${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar,${catalina.home}/lib,${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar 
sun.cpu.endian  little 
sun.io.unicode.encoding UnicodeLittle 
wtp.deploy  /home/pk/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps 
package.access  sun.,org.apache.catalina.,org.apache.coyote.,org.apache.tomcat.,org.apache.jasper. 
sun.cpu.isalist
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10 minutes ago i faced the same problem (for hours). I have a dynamic web project and i can create a web service from  a java class via context menu. the service is deployed to my local tomcat installation (containing axis2) but no wsdl is created.

But then i did a right click on my project and selected "run as" -> "run on server". Now it displays the "Apache Software Foundation" page. there is a link "services" on it. after clicking on the link it displays a "Available services" page with my deployed webservice. then i clicked on my own deployed web service and it displays the wsdl i was searching for. the url is something like:

```
http://localhost:8080/test/services/myservice?wsdl
```

"test" is my project name. The wsdl is not in my eclipse "WEB-INF/wsdl" folder (like in every tutorial i found so far). But i can access it only via the url above.